# url rewrite : how to remove value from url and make seo friendly url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

URL rewrites work perfectly for me. There's just one more thing:

I wanted to remove the value from the URL and parse the SEO friendly URL

For example: http://www.abc.com/bus/22/data-mapping-tech/loc 
I want to parse that URL into something like this:
http://www.abc.com/bus/data-mapping-tech/loc

Here, i dont want to do response.redirect and all. How i can handle that in process level?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is ASP.NET Routing.

This enables you to programatically transport your users to pages that correspond to a different more readable (SEO friendly) path

[Read more about it here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX)